# Class Diagrams relationships Interfaces

Tags: java, class, uml, diagrams

Say we have a class for exams and a class for course work, and both of these require the same attributes such as the courseword/exam id, name, deadline, weight etc.

Would it be wise to create an interface so both would implement the same methods such as what i've done below?
[[image]][
trying to look for the best OO approach, just not sure whether i'm going a little overkill.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach is to create a class  Class from whom ClassWork and ClassExam inherit.

The father class ClassF would declare those general attributes and the other 2 subclasses only will have to declare those specific attributes that make them unique 'cause the general ones are implied by inheritance.

I'll try to explain with an example:

```
       ClassF -> attributes: name, ID, weight, Date
              -> methods: getName() ....

             Exam -> attributes: marks 
                  -> methods: calculateMarks()...

             CourseWork -> attributes: typeOfCourse
                        -> methods: printInfoCourse()...
```

The subclasses Exam and CourseWork could implement and use for example, ID from ClassF because it's inherited from its father class.

Maybe it is a good idea to decide if you want to allow the instantiation of ClassF or not, because in that case it would be interesting to transform ClassF into an abstract class..

---

Just for the record in this concrete case the use of an interface to implement those classes is a wrong approach because that is not the function of an interface (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html for more info)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ah I like the idea of it. So say I wanted to add for example the weight of a specific course work or exam. Example: Coursework 1  = 25%, Coursework 2 = 25% and Exam = 50%. How would I implement this? what would be the approach? Also what If I want to have multiple course works or exams? wouldn't they need their own id's?

Comment: ClassF have that method, right? So the subclasses have it too but you want  a different behavior for each subclass and in that case you have to do an @overrided of the ClassF method. Is up to you if you want to change it completely or only add some functionality. BTW, this is polymorphism!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311788/when-to-implement-an-interface-and-when-to-extend-a-superclass

Comment: I understand the concepts just can't picture the best way of doing it, the diagram that I showed does ensure the use of polymorphism

Comment: In your UML diagram you only have to write the method's signature in all the classes that would implemented (same name and same parameters)