# Override class parameter type in Java

Tags: java, parameters, overriding

Is it possible to override a class parameter in Java? I'm pretty sure it is not possible but...

```
public class Dad {
  protected Building home;

  public Dad() {
  }

  public Building getHome(){
     return this.home;
  }
}

public class Son extends Dad {
  protected Shack home;

  public Son () {
    super();
    this.home = new Shack();
  }
}

public Shack extends Building{
 (...)
}
```

Apparently, there is no problem in adding two paraters with the same name but i'm not sure the two parameters are "link" together..

When I'm calling the `getHome()` function from a `Son` object, it returns a null object. Which make sense because the `Dad` object has no initialised `Building` object. Even if `Son` has a initialise `Shack` object that extends `Building` class. (I don't know if I'm clear enough...)

A simple solution would be to simply initialise `home` with a `Shack` object and cast `home` in `Shack` whenever it is necessary. But I'd like to know if there is another way to do this.

Comment: `super.home = ...`. But it would be better to pass it as a constructor parameter to `Dad`.

Comment: "i'm not sure the two parameters are "link" together.." They're not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields can't be overriden. In your case field from Son just [hiding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html) field from Dad:

> Within a class, a field that has the same name as a field in the
>   superclass hides the superclass's field, even if their types are
>   different. Within the subclass, the field in the superclass cannot be
>   referenced by its simple name. [...] Generally
>   speaking, we don't recommend hiding fields as it makes code difficult
>   to read.

The `GetHome` function declared into `Dad` class, so it can see only `home` instance form `Dad` which is null. You could access Dad's `home` as `super.home` from Son instance.

You could extract superclass or interface.

```
interface HasHome {
    Building getHome();
}

class Dad implements HasHome {
    protected Building home;

    public Dad() {
        this.home = new Building();
    }

    @Override
    public Building getHome(){
        return this.home;
    }
}

class Son implements HasHome { // Or extends Dad
    protected Shack home;

    public Son () {
        super();
        this.home = new Shack();
    }

    @Override
    public Shack getHome() {
        return home;
    }
}
```

There is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311788/when-to-implement-an-interface-and-when-to-extend-a-superclass) which way to choose. More over, supertype can be generic, as @Lorelorelore shows.

Answer (score 1):

You should not re-declare fields with the same names in subclasses. This is because fields are hidden, not overridden.

The compiler won't complain about this, but there are two variables in this case. `Dad.home` is not being assigned by the constructor in `Son`. So `new Son().getHome()` will return `null` in this example, and that's because `getHome()` only knows about `Dad.home`.

From where you are, the best is just to remove the `home` property from `Son`, and better yet, make it `private` in `Dad` and pass its value from the subclass using constructor parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should refactor those two classes with generics:

Abstract superclass:

```
public abstract class Person<T extends Building> {
    protected T home;

    public T getHome(){
        return this.home;
    }
}
```

Dad class:

```
public class Dad extends Person<Building> {

    public Dad() {
        home = new Building();
    }

}
```

Son class:

```
public class Son extends Person<Shack> {

    public Son () {
        home = new Shack();
    }

}
```

You can check if the `home` field has the correct type (and also not null) with a simple test:

```
public class SonAndDadTest {

    @Test
    public void sonTest(){
        Son son = new Son();
        Assert.assertNotNull(son.getHome());
        Assert.assertEquals(son.getHome().getClass(), Shack.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void dadTest(){
        Dad dad = new Dad();
        Assert.assertNotNull(dad.getHome());
        Assert.assertEquals(dad.getHome().getClass(), Building.class);
    }

}
```